# File that creates database tables

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am creating a template that uses a CMS and I will be giving it to other people. The web template requires a couple databases that I created in phpMyAdmin. If someone else is going to be using this they need the same tables, so I was wondering if there is a file I can write that they can install or run on their server that will create the databases and tables? Kind of like when you install Wordpress and it creates their tables for you.

Comment: Write all table creation queries in `php` file and then run it during installation of your CMS.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar "installing" is just going the be the user loading the files to their server. How would I do that?

Comment: As I said create one `PHP` file will all table creation queries. Tell the user to run this php file on your server and after that configure the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply export your database from within phpMyAdmin, and then have a PHP file that takes some inputs, like hostname, username, etc, which then runs the SQL dump.

Something like:

```
<?php

    if(!isset($_POST['hostname']))
        die('<input name="hostname" placeholder="Host name">' .
            '<input name="username" placeholder="Username">' .
            '<input name="password" placeholder="Password">' .
            '<input name="database" placeholder="Database">' .
            '<input type="submit">');

    $dh = mysqli_connect($_POST['hostname'], $_POST['username'],
                         $_POST['password'], $_POST['database']);

    mysqli_multi_query($dh, "-- Your dump file here

                      CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mytable` (
                       `mycolumn` VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL
                      ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

                      CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `another` (
                       `hello` INT(4) NOT NULL
                      ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
    ");

?>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in PDO?

Comment: okay so just take what you typed above and do it for all the databases and tables? So after mycolumn you would put a comma and the rest of the column names?

Comment: @zachstarnes Yes, but since you're using phpMyAdmin, it would be easier to just export your database with it. It will give you all of the relevant queries needed to recreate your database.

Comment: The input for the database name. It has to always be the same so wouldn't I just place the name of the database there?

Comment: @zachstarnes If that's the way your project requires it (i.e. you've hardcoded the db name in it), then yes. However this is bad practise... unless I've misunderstood you?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29158/discussion-between-zachstarnes-and-danny-beckett)

Answer (score 2):

What about using a `mysqldump` of tables involved in your cms template? You can check documentation [**here**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)
In this way you will have a dump of your tables' schema